# VSCode editor, increase font size for menus

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the VSCode editor (Windows10 64bit), is there a way to increase the font size for menus -- both dropdown and popup?

Comment: Have You tried? `Ctrl`+`+` and `Ctrl`+`-`

Comment: Yes, but it does not change the menu size at all for me. But it seems that it works for you. How so?

Comment: Look here http://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ , can you find something for yourself

Answer (score 15):

If you mean menus font-size **only** I realize in my attempt to answer the question I failed. Perhaps they expect such a setting be OS-level settable, I feel there is a need for it inside VScode just like there is editor and terminal font size options there should be the obvious **"menu.fontsize" : 14,**

However, if you would like to increase/decrease font-size of everything else in unison, then there is something the average user would not search for, I searched in the settings for "font" :)
For this you can add the following to your vscode/settings.json file:

```
"window.zoomLevel": 0.4
```

0 is default, it accepts decimals with a leading zero :) 0.4 works for my eyes.  I hope this helps someone

The settings embedded documentation currently says:
// Adjust the zoom level of the window. The original size is 0 and each increment above (e.g. 1) or below (e.g. -1) represents zooming 20% larger or smaller. You can also enter decimals to adjust the zoom level with a finer granularity.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly I am searching for , :)

Answer (score 1):

**Preferences -> Settings -> Window -> Zoom Level: 0**

*Adjust the zoom level of the window. The original size is 0 and each increment above (e.g. 1) or below (e.g. -1) represents zooming 20% larger or smaller. You can also enter decimals to adjust the zoom level with a finer granularity.*

Answer (score 0):

This setting will change the fontSize for certain items, like intellisense suggestions:

```
// Font size for the suggest widget

  "editor.suggestFontSize": 0,
```